# How to correctly store data (without db for now) in Android Jetpack Compose Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

Let's say I have a entity for example Dog. I wanna know how to store it's data and if this data changes at some point (using multiple threads) how to make sure it changes in UI as well. May I use classes to prevent having infinite number of ... by remember { mutableStateOf(...)}. And what if there are many Dogs? If somebody had a good example of such project I would be grateful.

I tried using UiState with ViewModels and also holding values in mutable variables but somehow every time I messed up something.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Jetpack DataStore](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/datastore), which has support for Kotlin Multiplatform. There are two types of DataStore: Preferences and Protobuf.

For starters, get yourself familiarized with Jetpack DataStore Preferences which provide an API to store your data in key-value, just like Shared Preferences, but the advantage you're looking for here is that it makes use of Kotlin Coroutines, and it fully supports Compose Multiplatform.

Jetpack DataStore provides a `collectAsState()` Compose extension function to track the data in real-time, and it will reflect the state of the data in Compose directly.